# filter a list with a table by multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table in database which is called `LineDocuments` and contains three columns:

```
public int Id { get; set;}
public int DocumentId { get; set;}
public int LineId { get; set;}
```

And i have a method which wants to add new `lineDocuments` but do not want to insert the `DocumentId` and `LineId` combination in a database table.

For example if there is already a record in a database like this exist:

`Id` - 1, `DocumentId` - 1, `LineId` - 1. And there comes a list with a record also with `DocumentId` - 1 and `LineId` - 1 do not allow to insert this record since it has already that combination.

What is appropriate way to filter this list ?

I have only add method for now, it looks like this:

```
public void AttachLinesToDocs(List<LineDocuments> linesDocuments)
{
    foreach (var lineDocument in linesDocuments)
    {
        dbConnection.LineDocuments.Add(lineDocument);
    }

    dbConnection.SaveChanges();
}
```

Hope everything is clear, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to insert a `LineDocuments` object with either a `DocumentId` or `LineId`? I'm not sure if it's me, but it's unclear what you're asking..

Comment: Edited in the question gave an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could check it first:

```
public void AttachLinesToDocs(List<LineDocuments> linesDocuments)
{
    var insertValid = from doc in linesDocuments
                      where !dbConnection.LineDocuments
                        .Any(x => x.DocumentId == doc.DocumentId && x.LineId == doc.LineId)
                      select doc;
    foreach (LineDocuments lineDocument in insertValid)
    {
        dbConnection.LineDocuments.Add(lineDocument);
    }
    dbConnection.SaveChanges();
}
```

This uses one query to check all documents before it saves the valid documents.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
public void AttachLinesToDocs(List<LineDocuments> linesDocuments)
{
  var qualifiedLineDocuments = linesDocuments.Where(inputld=> !dbConnection.LineDocuments.Any(ld=> ld.DocumentId== inputld.DocumentId && ld.LineId== inputld.LineId)).ToList();
      qualifiedLineDocuments.ForEach(qld=> 
      {
        dbConnection.LineDocuments.Add(qld);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: code without any description ?=! not a really elaborated answer

Comment: Well in method parameter I am passing an array not a single entity.

Comment: Sorry The mobile version is not that friendly. This code must go inside foreach loop.

Comment: @ajaysinghdav10d why don't you post your explanation inside your answer by editing it?

Comment: Well is it efficient to use foreach loop? I am looking for more efficient way. Maybe there is a more elegant way. :)

Comment: @CDSpace Please be mindful to only approve / improve edits that actually matter. This one should have been rejected as "No improvements whatsoever".